# how to edit shader for all materials

Tags: materials, scripting

I have an object that has 100+ materials, and the roughness in each material is set to 1, is there an easy way to set it to 0.5 with a script or smth?

Comment: just an advice for the future: you should have given us more infos about your material because i posted now just the "easiest" case. If you have more complicated material - you should have written that in your question. But you can open as many questions as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
import bpy

for eachSlot in bpy.data.objects["Cube"].material_slots:

    eachSlot.material.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[9].default_value = 0.5
```

But....

Prerequisites are:

1. all materials look like this:

[image]

2. you exchange "Cube" to the name of your object
3. Each slot must have an material which looks like 1)